# QT project crashing on profile, running with release and debugger

Tags: c++, qt

I have been working on a project which features multiple games. I am having an error when the user selects one of the games, the application crashes. This only happens in profile mode.
The error I get is from microsoft visual C++ runtime library:

> This applicaiton has request the Runtime to terminate in an unusual
>   way...

From reading online it seems that I am doing improper memory managment, I can't seem to figure out where the issue is. Here is my c++ source file:

```
#include "sticks.h"
#include "ui_sticks.h"
Sticks::Sticks(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Sticks)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
}

Sticks::~Sticks()
{
   delete ui;
}

int Sticks::selectUserChoice(int choice){
   ui->pushButton_select1->setEnabled(false);
   ui->pushButton_select2->setEnabled(false);
   ui->pushButton_select3->setEnabled(false);
   numsticks = numsticks - choice;
   //game_msg = "You grabbed " + QString::number(choice) + " sticks. There are " + QString::number(numsticks) + " sticks remaining";
   //setMessage(game_msg);
    computerChoice = getComputerChoice(numsticks);
    numsticks = numsticks - computerChoice;
   if (numsticks == 1)
       ui->pushButton_select1->setEnabled(true);
   if (numsticks == 2){
       ui->pushButton_select1->setEnabled(true);
       ui->pushButton_select2->setEnabled(true);
   }
   else{
       ui->pushButton_select1->setEnabled(true);
       ui->pushButton_select2->setEnabled(true);
       ui->pushButton_select3->setEnabled(true);
   }
}

   int Sticks::getComputerChoice(int current_sticks){
       /*Get a pseudo-random integer between 1 and 3 (inclusive)*/
       int choice = rand() % 3 + 1;

        if (current_sticks >=2 && current_sticks <=4){
            choice = current_sticks - 1;
    }
    else if (current_sticks == 1){
        return current_sticks;
    }
    return choice;
}

void Sticks::on_pushButton_select1_clicked()
{
selectUserChoice(1);
}

void Sticks::on_pushButton_select2_clicked()
{
   selectUserChoice(2);
}

void Sticks::on_pushButton_select3_clicked()
{
selectUserChoice(3);
}

void Sticks::on_pushButton_select_num_sticks_clicked()
{
    numsticks = ui->lineEdit_numsticks->text().toInt();
    if (numsticks < 10 || numsticks > 100) //Check that numsticks is 10-100
        return;
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "There are " << numsticks << " sticks remaining";
    std::string str = ss.str();
    QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(str);
    ui->label_current_sticks->setText(qstr);
    //ui->horizontalLayout->removeWidget(ui->pushButton_select_num_sticks);
    delete ui->pushButton_select_num_sticks;
    delete ui->lineEdit_numsticks;
    ui->pushButton_select1->setEnabled(true);
    ui->pushButton_select2->setEnabled(true);
    ui->pushButton_select3->setEnabled(true);
    ui->label_grab->setEnabled(true);
}

void Sticks::setMessage(QString msg){
    /*
    prev_msg3 = ui->label_msg3->text();
    prev_msg2 = ui->label_msg2->text();
    prev_msg1 = ui->label_msg1->text();
    ui->label_msg4->setText(prev_msg3);
    ui->label_msg3->setText(prev_msg2);
    ui->label_msg2->setText(prev_msg1);
    ui->label_msg1->setText(msg);
    */
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably is in this two lines:

```
delete ui->pushButton_select_num_sticks;
delete ui->lineEdit_numsticks;
```

You are deleting something that (I suppose) you are not dynamically allocating.

And be careful with this destructor:

```
Sticks::~Sticks()
{
   delete ui;
}
```

If you copy the `Sticks` objects you will copy the pointer `ui` too, so you are going to delete on same address multiple times.

Comment: This seems to be it, thanks! Now I just need to figure out how to remove the objects from the ui form properly.